# Compatibility issue between TensorFlow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a deep learning model using **TensorFlow** and **Keras**, but I am encountering some compatibility issues between the two libraries. Specifically, I am using TensorFlow 2.4.1 and Keras 2.4.3, but when I try to run my code, I get the following ***error message:***

```
C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe "C:\Users\soory\Downloads\Diabetic-retinopathy-detection-using-CNN-master\Diabetic-retinopathy-detection-using-CNN-master\web app\predict_app.py"
Using TensorFlow backend.
2023-03-20 21:29:49.528405: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2023-03-20 21:29:49.528656: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\soory\Downloads\Diabetic-retinopathy-detection-using-CNN-master\Diabetic-retinopathy-detection-using-CNN-master\web app\predict_app.py", line 5, in <module>
import keras

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import utils

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import conv_utils

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
from .. import backend as K

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .load_backend import epsilon

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
from .tensorflow_backend import *

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import keras

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras import models

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 37, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 51, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras import initializers

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\initializers__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
populate_deserializable_objects()

File "C:\Users\soory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\initializers__init__.py", line 80, in populate_deserializable_objects
generic_utils.populate_dict_with_module_objects(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

***The code is this :***

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

# Load an image using load_img
img = load_img('path/to/image.jpg')

# Convert the image to a numpy array using img_to_array
img_array = img_to_array(img)

from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Flask
import json
import h5py
from waitress import serve
import tensorflow as tf

app = Flask(__name__)


def fix_layer0(filename, batch_input_shape, dtype):
    with h5py.File(filename, 'r+') as f:
        model_config = json.loads(f.attrs['model_config'].decode('utf-8'))
        layer0 = model_config['config']['layers'][0]['config']
        layer0['batch_input_shape'] = batch_input_shape
        layer0['dtype'] = dtype
        f.attrs['model_config'] = json.dumps(model_config).encode('utf-8')


def get_model():
    global model, graph
    model = load_model('diabetic_retinopathy.h5')
    print(" * Model Loaded!!")
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()


def preprocess_image(image, target_size):
    if image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")
    image = image.resize(target_size)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    return image


print(" * Loading keras model.....")
fix_layer0('diabetic_retinopathy.h5', [None, 224, 224, 3], 'float32')
get_model()


@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    encoded = message['image']
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    with graph.as_default():
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        processed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size=(224, 224))
        prediction = model.predict(processed_image).tolist()
        response = {
            'prediction': {
                'dr': prediction[0][0],
                'nodr': prediction[0][1]
            }
        }
        return jsonify(response)

serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Comment: This is all happening during the `import`, before you have executed any code at all.  Have you checked that those versions are supposed to be compatible?

Answer (score 0):

For current versions, `keras` is part of the `tensorflow` package and you are not supposed to use the seperate `keras` package anymore. Thus, only import `tensorflow` like `import tensorflow as tf`, then replace any occurence of `keras` with `tf.keras`.